# Should I define indexes for both directions

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing

Using SQL Server 2012. Let's say I have a link table linking item & size

The table might look like

`itemSize`:

```
itemSizeId (int)
itemId (int)
sizeId (int)
```

If I define a composite index on `itemId & sizeId` so that I can quick look for an item by size should I also define an index for `sizeId & itemId` or is the alternate direction covered by the first index?

Comment: When doing a composite index, you are able to take advantage of the index from its left most arguments first.  For example, a composite index of (ItemID, SizeID) will allow you to do an index lookup via ItemID, or ItemID and SizeID.  If you need to do an index lookup of SizeID alone, then you could do what you're asking, otherwise I think it would be a pointless index.

Comment: What is the purpose of the `itemSizeId` column? What does it identify that the unique combination of `itemId` and `sizeId` cannot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should define an index based on the queries that you want to use on it.

If you want to do queries that have:

```
where itemId = @itemId
```

and
    where size = @size

(and no other clauses on these two fields), then you should have two different indexes.

This is also true if you want SQL Server to use the index for other purposes, such as for an `order by`.